# InterlockedPushEntrySList's Performance

Tags: c++, windows, lock-free, interlocked

I'm Testing WinAPI InterlockedPushEntrySList
but my test result is a little weird.

I thought basically in LockFree, push speed will be faster as thread increase.
because one thread will success push at least.
in my test as thread increase InterlockedPushEntrySList's speed slower.

my test was very simple. just perform push behavior in multithread.
I eliminated all another factor that caused miss test.

thread 1 : 138,075,326
thread 2 : 131,584,007
thread 3 : 90,196,884
therea 4 : 82,699,521

It's count of push for 5 seconds

plz tell me why.ㅠ
did Nobody test this?

Comment: I don't understand why you think the operation gets faster the more contention you have. The operation takes the same amount of time for the winner and takes longer for the losers.

Comment: It was my mistake, actually I mean at least same speed with 1 thread when we make contention with N threads.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought basically in LockFree, push speed will be faster as thread
>   increase.

If that was the case, we would all write lock free code and launch thousands of threads having infinite speed, isn't it?

"Lock-Free" just means the algorithm will not use a lock to achieve synchronization, but use atomic operations instead (most prominent a CAS loop).

It doesn't mean that a lock free algorithm will run faster than a non-lock free algorithm (it usually does).

It doesn't mean that lock free will be slower or faster depending on the number of threads (it usually becomes slower as the thread count increase)

In your case, as there are more threads, they will have to "fight" harder to get their operation to succeed, this is usually the case in multi-threaded code. the more you share between threads and the more they exists - the contention will hurt your performance. lock-free may **ease** the problem, but not **solve** it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my case, as there are many threads, and they will fight! but there is always a winner. so multi-thread will have same  speed or be faster than 1-thread at least. It's my basic theory of LockFreeAlgorithm. Isn't right? ㅠ

Comment: You're assuming that the "winning" write is just as fast as an uncontested write, and I don't think that's true.  The hardware has to do extra work to cope with the contention - to make sure each CPU knows whether it won or lost - and it seems to me that that's bound to slow things down.

Comment: Thank you! Can I get some link or Information about "extra work" plz? I want to get more detail...!

Comment: @chfhrqnfRhc do you understand why in non-lock-free code the larger the thread count the slower pushing an entry gets?

Comment: yeah. when they meet LOCK only one thread will process task and another thread(meet LOCK) will be blocked. In this situation context switching will be occur, performance will be down. but  lock free use spin when they couldn't get ..so I think, any context switching cost. sorry my bad english. ㅠㅠ